# How can I elegantly represent Gravity?

Tags: symbolism

I need to represent 4 things in a simple, pictographic form. I've got the first 3, for Wind, Water and Ice - but I need one for gravity in the same style. I'm struggling because gravity is not visible.

Here are the 3 for Wind, Water and Ice:

<sup>Update: Made all lines the same width, removed swirls from water:</sup>

[image]

#### Update - my decision for the gravity icon:

[image]

Comment: I don't feel it fits well with the others.  Also, is there a reason for the varied line thickness?  The snowflake, wind, and water all have different thicknesses.  I'm also not a fan of the curls above the water.   Just my opinion.

Comment: Should there be a (visible) "connection" between the pictograms?

Comment: @elegent They should all be similar styles - I'd like it to be predominantly lines.

Comment: @JohnManly I need to make the wind thinner. Unfortunately, that's not as simple as it sounds - I downloaded that and it's not lines, it's an area. I could probably do it though. The water looked very sparse without the swirls - let me add another wavy line above. And no, it doesn't fit - hence my request :)

Comment: I see. Maybe a starting point for gravity: wind is also not visible... ;)

Comment: @elegent Hmm, the pattern for wind shows the path things take when influenced by it. I could do the same for gravity, as the answer suggests.

Comment: If it's an Adobe Illustrator file, simply offset the path, with a negative value, and it will make the area smaller.

Comment: @JohnManly I'm using Inkscape - I did that but it looked a bit funny from where I'd edited it. I redrew it with a line.

Comment: Part of the problem may simply be that the other icons are blue while the offending one is grey?

Comment: Its the line weight and the sharp angles: they don't feel cohesive as a set. Also the Ice one isn't working either. The wind and water work together the bottom two not so much.

Answer (score 5):

Going with line art, here are some examples that follow the same style.

One idea that uses movement is showing the direction of gravity towards a surface.

[image: gravity example]

Another idea is to show an object slowly losing height.

[image: gravity example 2]

Comment: Which program did you make these in out of interest?

Comment: @Metasomatism Adobe Illustrator

Comment: My initial thought was your first diagram exactly

Comment: @Metasomatism I think the second idea is closer to what will be needed. As mentioned before, many people associate gravity with Newton and therefore an image of something falling or losing height over time will give a better representation. The arrows are too ambiguous.

Comment: As a layman, I like the ball image. I think it depicts gravity, but something about the blue that helps keep it with the rest your images. However, it feels like your wind and water are so simple in comparison to the ice, and gravity. $ .02

Comment: @user63551 Yes, I'm looking for it to be simple... I think they're both too busy.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use an apple instead of a rock it would be more efficient as many people have the idea of gravity associated with an apple falling into Newton's head.

Comment: _"many people have the idea of gravity associated with an apple falling into Newton's head"_ Do they? I'm not so sure. I'm not convinced that most "lay people" I know are even _aware_ of this particular part of scientific history.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet you're probably correct—and that makes me sad.

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with your current line work possibly something along the lines of this? It is only a quick idea but as a representation of the forces of gravity it could help.

[image]